# I can't write to a SQLLite database in my AIR app

Tags: sqlite, actionscript, air

I am publishing an AIR app in debug mode using FlashDevelop and have included a database in the files/folders to be published. 
When the app first launches it checks whether there is an instance of this db in the applicationStorageDirectory, if there isn't it copies the included one from the applicationDirectory to the applicationStorageDirectory. 
This should mean that the referenced database `dbFile = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath(DB_FILE_NAME);`  should now be writable, however when i run the app i can read the records from the table but when i attempt to write using an SQL statement I get an SQLError: 'Error #3122: Attempt to write a readonly database'.

I know that this would be thrown if i was attempting to write to the read only location of the applicationDirectory but i'm certainly using the File.applicationStorageDirectory location which should (as far as i know) be writable.

The location of the db on my Windows 7, 64bit = C:\Users\sean.duffy\AppData\Roaming\FishFightAppData\Local Store\db this is found using the dbFile.nativePath property so again i'm sure i should be able to update the db.

Anyone got any ideas? I have tried everything i could think of and searched all over but the only common cause seems to be when people try to write to the asplicationDirectory and not the storage directory....

**UPDATE::**

My bad - have just realised that i've misread the API of the 3rd party library i'm using! I should have been calling executeModify(statement) which can modify the contents of the db, instead i'm calling execute(statement) which doesn't/can't overwrite the db.

The source code is compiled into a swc and there was no documentation to point out you needed to use executeModify, although i should have guessed from the name i suppose!

Sorry about that and thanks for your help

Comment: Turn on UAC, and see if you can rename your db file from a "unelevated" command prompt window. (Eg: not running as administrator). with its location, it should be able to proform this task. but if it can't it would show why the air app can't touch it too. Also, What is stored in "DB_FILE_NAME" ?? is it a backslash or a forward slash? If back, it will need 2 backslashes.

Comment: Yes it can rename the file from the cmd prompt (non-administrator rights) also i am using a forward slash for the DB_FILE_NAME:String = "db/fishfight.db"; Is there any way the internal contents of the db could be set to read only? I created it using a freeware AIR app called Lita but i couldn't see any setting for this (you can encrypt it and password protect it but nothing for read/write permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(As a public courtesy to get this off the unanswered list, I am reposting the apparent solution. As usual, the asker is more than welcome to ignore mine and post it themselves and accept their own answer.)

In this API, you need to call `executeModify(statement)`, not `execute(statement)`. The latter does not overwrite the database.